# Can I transform a JSON-LD to a Java object?

Tags: java, json, jena, json-ld

**EDIT**: I changed my mind. I would find a way to generate the Java class and load the JSON as an object of that class.

---

I just discovered that exists a variant of `JSON` called `JSON-LD`.

It seems to me a more structured way of defining `JSON`, that reminds me `XML` with an associated schema, like `XSD`.

Can I create a Java class from `JSON-LD`, load it at runtime and use it to convert `JSON-LD` to an instantiation of that class?

I read the documentation of both the implementations but I found nothing about it. Maybe I read them bad?

Comment: The question is too broadly and poorly worded. Everything in Java is either a primitive or Object. So the quick answer: yes. JSON-LD is a fromat for representing RDF. RDF is representing in Java as a RDF Graph or RDF Model, that wraps a Graph. All these things - are instantions of json-ld, in your terms, and, obiviously, are java Object's.  So, please clarify - why you can't work with RDF?

Comment: @ssz I think "with jsonld-java, or Apache Jena" makes it very specific...

Comment: @ssz: furthermore JSON-LD does not represent RDF. JSON-LD can be [trasnformed to an RDF model](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSON-LD#Design). And RDF models are not Java objects at all, they must be converted. So ok, you're suggesting to convert JSON-LD to RDF and then RDF to a Java object. Is it correct? Is there not a library that directly converts from JSON-LD to a Java object?

Comment: "JSON-LD is a concrete RDF syntax": [https://www.w3.org/TR/json-ld](https://www.w3.org/TR/json-ld/#relationship-to-rdf) That means any json-ld document can be represent as a RDF Graph (maybe in generic sense). RDF - is not a format at all, to be convertible from some other format. But it is representation data in RDF form. There is a powerful API to work with it - Apache Jena, which uses `com.github.jsonld-java:json-ld` API as a parser. If you don't want to use any RDF API, just only parser, than, perhaps you have to write your own model-API.

Comment: When we say 'model' we usually means not only raw data, but also facilities to work with this data. Anything in Java is an `Object` (or primitives). So any model in Java is a `Object`, which, at least partially, lies in memory. So, the original requiest 'give me an Object' sounds strange to me.

Comment: Admit, that JSON-LD is a little bit more wide, than RDF, but usually it is used exactly for RDF serialization (dataset or graph). So, if there is no blank predicates, it can loaded as a Graph or Dataset, which are java `Object`s, if the used API is written on Java. By the way, a Graph may be backed by the triple store, so may not fully be present in memory.

Comment: @ssz: well, my intention is not to use it for RDF serialization, but as a substitute for JSON. I would use it as an alternative to XML, that has also a schema that tells you how the XML is structured. If I understood well, JSON-LD contains the data and the schema. Or am I wrong?

Comment: I would not say that. But in case of RDF,  the document in JSON-LD format can relly RDFS and OWL - in this sense it has a schema. When you are dealing with OWL - you also have classes, individuals, and other ontological stuff with different relations between them.

Answer (score 1):

Doing a Google search brought me to a library that will decode the JSON-LD into an "undefined" `Object`.

```
// Open a valid json(-ld) input file
InputStream inputStream = new FileInputStream("input.json");
// Read the file into an Object (The type of this object will be a List, Map, String, Boolean,
// Number or null depending on the root object in the file).
Object jsonObject = JsonUtils.fromInputStream(inputStream);
// Create a context JSON map containing prefixes and definitions
Map context = new HashMap();
// Customise context...
// Create an instance of JsonLdOptions with the standard JSON-LD options
JsonLdOptions options = new JsonLdOptions();
// Customise options...
// Call whichever JSONLD function you want! (e.g. compact)
Object compact = JsonLdProcessor.compact(jsonObject, context, options);
// Print out the result (or don't, it's your call!)
System.out.println(JsonUtils.toPrettyString(compact));
```

https://github.com/jsonld-java/jsonld-java

Apparently, it can take it from just a string as well, as if reading it from a file or some other source. How you access the contents of the `object`, I can't tell. The documentation seems to be moderately decent, though.

It seems to be an active project, as the last commit was only 4 days ago and has 30 contributors. The license is BSD 3-Clause, if that makes any difference to you.

I'm not in any way associate with this project. I'm not an author nor have I made any pull requests. It's just something I found.

Good luck and I hope this helped!

Comment: And can I put also a specific class instead of `Object jsonObject`? Is there a way to create the class from the JSON-LD itself?

Comment: @MarcoSulla, I'm sure you could use Reflection to drop it into a class, and there might even be a way to do it automatically. I haven't used that library, so I don't know.

Answer (score 0):

see this page: [JSON-LD Module for Jackson](https://github.com/io-informatics/jackson-jsonld)

Comment: Well, but I have to create the class by hand :P

Comment: This chain may be possible: [JSON-LD file] --{JSON-LD for Jackson}-> [Java Object] --{Jackson or Gson}-> [JSON file] --{jsonschema2pojo}-> [Java Class]

Comment: I don't know how `{JSON-LD for Jackson}-> [Java Object]` is possible without the class...